# Two \social icons for one account name in moderncv header?

Tags: moderncv, fontawesome

I use the default template of moderncv (can be used as MWE) classic style with awesome moderncvicons compiled in LuaLaTeX. I have the same account name for Twitter and Github, and I would like to have both icons in the same line preceding my account name in the header info. Here is the part of the template:

```
\social[linkedin]{john22.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
```

How can I do this? Thanks for your replies.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\social` macro is meant to contain only one nick per social site, since it also inserts a link to the social website in question.

To get both on one line you could use the `\extrainfo` field that allows you to insert some arbitrary information in the headers:

```
\extrainfo{\githubsocialsymbol~\twittersocialsymbol~jdoe}
```

Comment: @user2498456 glad I could help. Please consider accepting the answer if this worked.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the answer of Bordaigorl, and in an attempt to keep the links to the social sites in some way, I added hyperlinks to the icons.

```
\extrainfo{\href{https://www.github.com/jdoe}{\githubsocialsymbol}~%
           \href{https://www.twitter.com/jdoe}{\twittersocialsymbol}~%
           jdoe}
```